# Combining and resizing barplot and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two plots I would like to combine. My data looks like this:

```
Year<-rep(2001:2005, each = 5)
name<-c("John","Ellen","Mark","Randy","Luisa")
Name<-c(rep(name,5))
Value<-sample(seq(0,25,by=1),25)
mydata<-data.frame(Year,Name,Value)
```

This is the first barplot:

```
tot<-aggregate(mydata$Value,list(mydata$Year),FUN=sum)
tot_y<-tot$x
tot_x<-tot$Group.1

tot_barplot <- ggplot(tot, aes(x=tot_x,y=tot_y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="#73D055FF") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 125), breaks = seq(0, 125, by = 25)) +
  #xlab("Pathways") + 
  #ylab("N° of species") +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,margin=margin(l=10),colour="black"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank()) 
tot_barplot
```

And this is the second plot:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=Year, y=Name, size = Value)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = Value, 
                 alpha = I(as.numeric(Value > 0))),  shape=21, colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "D", direction = -1,limits = c(1, 25), breaks=seq(1, 25, 5))+
  scale_size_area(guide = "none") +
  ylab("Name") + 
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=11,margin=margin(b=10),colour="black"),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=13,margin=margin(l=10),colour="black",
                                 face="italic"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_text(size=18,face="bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18))
p
```

I combine them like this:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(tot_barplot,p,nrow=2))
```

Now I would like to re-size the barplot to fit it better to the second plot (imagine that the original data produce a wider barplot where the bars start above the `Name` and end above the legend `Value`). I would like the bars of the barplot to be exactly centred above the line of points and the `Year`, but I am not very familiar with ggplot aesthetics.
Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, `patchwork` package will help you arrange ggplot objects neatly: https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/

Comment: You could add ```plot.margin = unit(c(0,0.1,0,0.05), "npc")``` to the theme in tot_barplot for adding margins left and right to the bars. Not a perfect solution and you might need try different parameter for achieving best fit.

Comment: Hi @yh6, that worked perfectly, thank you! And many thanks to Wolfgang too.